# Is there any way to play MP3 files in Google Drive

Tags: mp3, google-drive

I have uploaded MP3 files to my Google Drive. Can I play them there? They allow video files so I was thinking they might allow streaming MP3 files as well.

If not, is there any way that I can store MP3s in Google Drive but play them online using some service?

There is an iPhone app which lets you play music from Google Drive but I want a website which can do that.

Comment: It seems possible through SyncDocs: http://techmemore.com/music-in-google-docs/

Answer (score 1):

Google don't want this as a service as they have just released a new music service. However, there is a service http://www.g2themax.com/ that allows you to play mp3 files stored in Gdocs. But Google may have blocked this.

Comment: actually google music service is only for US

Comment: For the moment, but it would explain why Googlee are reserved in allowing mp3 streaming. You can just upload mp3 and play through your browser but I think you are looking for a more service orientated approach?